# Parallelized machine learning (recommendation) algorithm with hadoop

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, hdfs, apache-spark, matrix-factorization

I am working on a recommendation algorithm : **Matrix Factorization using a stochastic gradient as optimizer.**

I would like to parallelized my algorithm. I found this article [Parallelized Stochastic Descent Gradient](http://www.research.rutgers.edu/~lihong/pub/Zinkevich11Parallelized.pdf). 
They give an algorithm (p3):

```
Algorithm 3 SimuParallelSGD(Examples {c1, . . . cm}, Learning Rate η, Machines k)

Deﬁne T = ⌊m/k⌋
Randomly partition the examples, giving T examples to each machine.
for all i ∈ {1, . . . k} parallel do
  Randomly shufﬂe the data on machine i.
  Initialize w(i,0) = 0.
  for all t ∈ {1, . . . T }: do
    Get the tth example on the ith machine (this machine), c(i,t)
    w(i,t) ← w(i,t−1) − η∂(w)  ci*(wi,t−1)
  end for
end for
Aggregate from all computers v = 1/k SUM(W(i,t) and return v.
```

And they commented with :

> "The algorithm requires no communication
>   between machines until the end. This is perfectly suited to MapReduce settings."

I can't see how they implement it. Did they distribute the data on each machine "*manually*"? or using *HDFS*?

As HDFS take care of distribution of the data; how can I restrict my program to work only with the data, on his current data-node?

Is there a suited way to implement it with a **spark + hadoop cluster**?

Any leads is welcome

---

I forgot to mention something. I saw the example **regression logistic** with **SGD** on spark.

But the dataset is just a

```
      UserID | ItemID | ratings
```

and in my case to reinforce the the algorithm we add some Users informations and Items information. So I have two more files (UserID age sex..) and (ItemID color size..) that I need on each data-node in order to complete the computation.

I was thinking maybe to put the number of replicate of HDFS equal to the number of machines and in this way all the data will be on each node. But the thing I don't know is when I will do on spark that:

```
 val textFile = sc.textFile("README.md")
```

1. What will happen?
2. Will rdd be created on each datanode's memory?
3. Does all the task could be process only in local by each datanode?

Answer (score 2):

It is the same algorithm that Spark uses in its examples under logistic regression:

http://spark.apache.org/examples.html

Yes, all methods rely on the splitting the data in blocks, which is what HDFS natively does.
In the MapReduce setting, every mapper would do the inner-most for-loop and the reducer would aggregate the results from all computers. To converge you will need to run this multiple times- thus scheduling many MapReduce jobs.

As a practical side-note, the shuffling before the stochastic step is usually left out. It requires to either rewrite the data or fully memory-map+shuffle it at every iteration- both are quite costly.

Comment: I forgot to mention something. I saw this example and it works when the dataset is just a "UserID ItemID ratings", but in my case to reinforce the the algorithm we add some Users informations and Items informations. So I have two more files (UserID age sex..) and (ItemID color size..) that I need on each datanode in order to complete the computation...

Comment: @GermainGum then join them into your textfile in a first job and in the usual stochastic GD you can use that as your feature.

Comment: Yes multiple MR jobs means this would be super slow in Hadoop.  You can get like a 100x speed up in Spark.

Comment: The spark example is not the same algorithm. The spark example is regular batch gradient descent. The algorithm in question is similar, but performs SGD on each local machine and then averages the resultant weight vectors (not the gradients) to produce the final output.

Comment: @Raff.Edward Yes I agree, you would need to put the weight update into the map call.

Comment: Thanks for yours answers, I got yours points.
Do you know how the memory of Spark work? If for each computation the data are not present locally and spark have to wait the network load to do the computation. I will win some time on computation thanks to spark memory (or cache) but loose it during the network load, no?

Comment: @GermainGum why should spark read over the network? That behaviour is depending on your underlying filesystem. Spark takes care about data locality on HDFS.

Comment: Tell me if I am wrong, if I have 10Go of data (the values are just for the example), 4datanodes, I will have 2,5Go on each datanodes (and no replica). For the computation I need 7,5Go of the data, the 5Go which are not present locally would have to be loaded by a network communication no?

Comment: @GermainGum why would you have no replication?

Comment: Because how i see it in the regression example each line (UserID,ItemID,Ratings) of the file are distributed on machines, and the computation will work with what it has on his machine. But my files  (UserID age sex..) and (ItemID color size..) will also be distributed on machines and for the computation I need all of the lines.
Maybe my way of seeing these things is completely false. I am kind of new to these technologies.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut it was for the example. Sure I will fave some replica, but may be the data that I need for the computation won't be locally. (replica=2 ; 5Go on each machines, and I need 7,5 to do the computation)

Comment: @GermainGum no idea what you are talking about, when you upload stuff to HDFS, you can't place files on a server. You shouldn't care about that. For your multiple files issue: I already told you to join them before you actually start the SGD.

Comment: Sorry if I am unclear. What I understand is, the goal of Hadoop/Spark cluster is to distribute the data via HDFS, I will not have like 2To on a single machine but divided on several machines. But the map part will be process on each machines, and what if all the data that I need for this process aren't in the local datanode? How can I be sure all the data needed for the map part will be local?